# Question about iAd being displayed on iPad & iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

In my App, I display and iAd but I was hoping for clarification on a few things:

1) If I display an Ad, it does not look like it will 'automagically' go away, so am I correct that it is my responsibility to dismiss it?

2) I thought I read somewhere that it must stay for a min. 30 seconds. Is that correct?

3) Is it wrong to leave it there forever and let the user dismiss it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If I display an Ad, it does not
>   look like it will 'automagically' go
>   away, so am I correct that it is my
>   responsibility to dismiss it?

Are you talking about a banner or the full screen ad? The banner ad is either updated with a new ad after 30 seconds, or if there is no ad, then the banner view is to be hidden. You are never supposed to show the banner view if there is no ad to be displayed. To learn how to hide the banner view, code samples are in the developer docs. There have also been many topics about this on this site.

You are not supposed to dismiss an iAd. If the full screen ad is being shown, the user dismisses it. There is a delegate callback to handle this.

> 2) I thought I read somewhere that it
>   must stay for a min. 30 seconds. Is
>   that correct?

I've never heard this, but read the above. It will stay for 30 seconds on it's own, no need to dismiss it. If the user is changing views to a view that has no iAd, then you don't need to do anything. But, there is a way to have the banner show on each view. To do that, see the 'iAdSuite' project at developer.apple.com

```
3) Is it wrong to leave it there forever and let the user dismiss it?
```

This is exactly what you should be doing (while there is an ad to be displayed). I really encourage you to read the iAd Programming Guide found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have read the Programming Guide as well as countless other docs... and it can be overwhelming.  In any event, I just want clarity and maybe a sanity check.  YES, I do have code that dismisses the iAd, but in my testing I have found that without me do anything the test ad comes and goes about every 3 to 5 minutes.  Because of that I wanted to hear what others say about leaving it.  Becuase it is a banner and does not really obstruct any view on my app, I thought I could just leave it and let them come and go.  Of course, if none are available I would leave it off screen.  Make sense?

Comment: @Tony, you're dead right. I have had mixed results with the test ads, they don't function very well. I think they intentionally do this so you can test for odd scenarios. My advice is to follow what they say in the docs, make sure it fits what you want to do, and leave it. The real ads act as promised, refreshing every 30 seconds.

Comment: Cool, if they act as promised and refresh every 30 seconds, then hopefully there is nothing wrong with leaving them there and as they come in the banner will change... if there is no ad, it will be hidden off screen.

Comment: Exactly, just use the delegate callbacks to move the banner view on and off screen and that's really all you need for a basic implementation.